# Twilio Easy Call plugin

Tags: plugins

I installed a plugin to my website called [Twilio Easy Call](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twl-easy-call/).

The plugin description says I have to put the shortcode on a page.

Any idea how I can place this shortcode? Is it just copy/paste?

Comment: Looking at the [plugin's screenshot](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twl-easy-call/screenshots/), it appears that the shortcode is displayed on the plugin's Settings page.

Comment: Nice ... i just took it copy/paste it works with me and the button apeared (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wpc2c number='your_phone_number_here']